# Judgemental equality

Tags: types, agda

TL;DR: in Agda, given `a : A` and `proof : A == B`, can I obtain an element `a : B`?

---

In my ongoing attempt to learn Agda, I've created the following `Prime : nat -> Set` datatype, which is a witness to the primality of a natural.

```
Prime zero = False
Prime (succ zero) = False
Prime (succ (succ n)) = forall {i : nat} -> divides i p -> i <N p -> zero <N i -> i == (succ zero)
  where
    p = succ (succ n)
```

Here:

- `False` is a data type with no constructors;
- `divides a b` is a data type that contains a witness `k` to the fact that `a * k = b`;
- `a <N b` is a data type that contains a witness `k` to the fact that `a + k = b`;
- `==` is the equality type, with just one constructor `refl`;
- the natural numbers are defined in the obvious way with `zero : nat` and `succ : nat -> nat`.

I've successfully exhibited a member of `Prime (succ (succ zero))`, and proved that the statement `Prime (succ (succ (succ (succ zero)))))` implies `False`.

Now I'm trying to prove that primes are greater than one:

```
primesAreGreaterThanOne : (p : Sg nat Prime) -> (succ zero <N value p)
```

where

- `Sg A pred` is the dependent pair `(p, pred(p))` where `p : A`;
- `value : Sg A pred -> A` extracts the value and discards the proof.

I've already proved trichotomy of the order: for all `a, b` it is true either that `a <N b`, or `a == b`, or `b <N a`. (This lemma, I hope, should help us avoid any excluded-middle problems.) So by working casewise on the ordering relation between `succ zero` and `value p`, I've reduced to the case that I have a proof of `p == zero` and a proof of `Prime p` and the statement that `Prime zero` is defined to be False.

Now, of course, these statements are contradictory: since I have a proof that `p == zero`, I can exhibit an inhabitant of the type `Prime p == Prime zero`, and hence I have an inhabitant of `Prime p == False`.

But how can I take my element `proof : Prime p` (the proof which is the second component of `p : Sg nat Prime`) and "cast" it to an element of `False`? The types are propositionally equal, but not judgementally equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to point out some theoretical background on this particular topic.

Agda's core is Martin Löf's logical framework (LF), which is a minimal dependently typed lambda calculus that gives us the dependent functions among other things. And overall, Agda is based on intensional ML type theory.

In LF, there is a rule called type conversion rule which states that

```
 Γ ⊢ t : A     Γ ⊢ A = B
--------------------------
        Γ ⊢ t : B
```

This coerces terms along type equality. Where two types are definitionally equal established by computation (beta) and extensionality (eta).

Edit to clarify:
In intensional TT, judgmental equality and propositional equality are separated and propositional equality doesn't give you judgmental. If you want a rule that given two propositionally equal terms to be also judgmentally equal, then you would be in an extensional TT, which is often undesirable since it makes type checking undecidable. So, in intensional TT, it is not always true.

Comment: That's definitional equality, not propositional one. You can't generally derive `t : B` from `t : A, A = B` (where `=` is propositional) without some kind of extensionality.

Comment: Right, I was thinking with eta conversion, but I guess that would move away from intensional TT.

Answer (score 5):

This turns out to be easy; Just Do It (tm).

```
typeCast : {a : _} {A : Set a} {B : Set a} (el : A) (pr : A == B) -> B
typeCast {a} {A} {.A} elt refl = elt
```